# C# - can I derive from class with generic base type?

Tags: c#

**Intro**

I am creating an ASP.NET Web API application with Entity Framework. What I need to do is return different representations of the same resource for one URI, depending on user role. For example, `api/employees/1` will return two different objects for admin and standard user:

*Standard user*

```
public class EmployeeBasic 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

*Admin*

```
public class EmployeeExtended : EmployeeBasic 
{
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

**The idea and the attempts**

For each resource representation, I will need to provide some related classes, let's say Sort Models for example. I was wondering if it is possible to use generic types and inheritance to create a generic repository methods for related representations. I thought of the following way of doing this:

1. Create some base interface for Sort Models:

   ```
    public interface ISortModel<out TBusinessEntity> 
    {
        //
    }
   ```
2. Create generic SortModel as a base type for all sort models

   ```
     public abstract class SortModel<TDBEntity, TBusinessEntity> : ISortModel<TBusinessEntity>
     {
          // Database sorting
          public abstract IQueryable<TDBEntity> ApplyToQuery(IQueryable<TDBEntity> query);

          // Local sorting
          public abstract IEnumerable<TBusinessEntity> ApplyToLocal(IEnumerable<TBusinessEntity> localList);

          // ...
          // Some private logic (expression mappers, etc.)
    }
   ```
3. Create sort model for basic resource

   ```
    public class EmployeeBasicSortModel : SortModel<DBModel.Employee, EmployeeBasic>
    {
        public int FullName { get; set; }

        public override IQueryable<DBModel.Employee> ApplyToQuery(IQueryable<DBModel.Employee> query) 
        {
            // implementation
        }

        public override IEnumerable<EmployeeBasic> ApplyToLocal(IEnumerable<EmployeeBasic> localList) 
        {
            // implementation
        }
    }
   ```
4. Extend the basic sort model and add sorting for the extended resource properties

   ```
    public class EmployeeExtendedSortModel : EmployeeBasicSortModel //, ... Is it possible to somehow do that?
    {
        public override IEnumerable<EmployeeExtended> ApplyToLocal(IEnumerable<EmployeeExtended> localList) 
        {
            var partiallyOrderedList = base.ApplyToLocal(localList);

            // Add extended sorting
        }

        // ... ?
    }
   ```
5. Use the above classes to create generic service:

   ```
    class EmployeesService() 
    {
        public IList<TEmployee> GetAll<TEmployee>(ISortModel<TEmployee> sortModel)
               where TEmployee : BasicEmployee
        {
            // implementation
        }
    }
   ```

**The problem**

When I thought about it for the first time, it seemed pretty simple. But when I started implementing this, I couldn't figure out the way to implement Step 4. Either I am missing something in my C# knowledge (which is quite possible) or this is not possible in the way I am trying to do this.

So the question is: can I create a base class with generic type, derive from it with basic resource as a type and derive one more time with the extended class?

Comment: Sounds massively overcomplicated. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking if you can inherit a generic type where the type parameter is one thing (e.g. `EmployeeBasic`) but then override members using a different type (e.g. `EmployeeExtended`). If so, then the answer is no, you can't do that, and for the same reason the answer is "no" for the hundreds of other identical Stack Overflow questions asking the same thing: it's not type-safe. If you are asking something else, please edit your question so it's clear what you are asking. Be sure to explain why this is specific to ASP.NET, since you added those tags.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I think that this answers my question.

@Mardoxx Maybe it is, but I also gave oversimplified example. I have more classes and each has much more properties than in the example. Some of the properties are encrypted in database and that's why I needed separate database and local sorting/filtering. Having self-resolving sort/filter models let me prepare a universal querying mechanism instead of bunch of if/else statements in each service method:

https://pastebin.com/Hsp095L8 - this internally executes query with filters, decrypts entity and applies local sorting/filtering

Comment: However, it was much more convenient until I realised that I need more than one representation for each resource. Then, what I wanted to achieve was: (1) avoid getting extended entity from database and then mapping it to restricted view models (this would execute unneeded sql queries) and thus: (2) modify my generic querying mechanism to support different resource representations. However, it indeed seems to be too complicated and I will either create separate service methods or use the (1) approach.

Comment: Instead of using inheritance to achieve this, and based on the fact that you are trying to manipulate *behavior* rather than data, why not use a `Func` as a parameter to your sorting logic. Then your class(es) can pass in different ways to sort to the base sorting logic.You define the basic sorting framework in the base class, then the derived classes pass in the sorting behavior that they wish to use.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good idea, thanks! I think I will go this way. If you add this as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have been here. I have gone down the rabbit hole of madness with generics and inheritance. It never turned into anything productive. And if, by some miracle, it made sense, it would never survive the first unforeseen change. And no one else would be able to understand it. It calls to us like moths to the flame, like sirens to sailors, but it ends in despair and compiler errors about covariance and contravariance that are always right even though we can't explain why.

Comment: Nicely said. Thanks to all the comments, I noticed that this approach was not the best one to my problem. Or maybe to any problem. It's time to take a step back and rethink the idea. But now, it's time to go to sleep. :-) Thanks for help to all of you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Holy goodness this is a complicated question. The generics are a huge red herring. Ignore the generics; the problem is more fundamental. Let's simplify it greatly.

```
class Animal {}
class Mammal : Animal {}
class Tiger : Mammal {}

class Shape {}
class Square : Shape {}
class GreenSquare : Square {}

class B
{
  public virtual Mammal Frob(Square s) { ... }
}

class D : B
{
  public override SomeReturnType Frob(SomeArgumentType m) { ... }
}
```

The question is: what are legal return and argument types for this virtual override?

The answer is: in C# the only legal types are those that exactly match the overridden method's types.  An override of Frob must return Mammal and take Square.

Now, we *could* in theory make it typesafe for D.Frob to *return Tiger*. Do you see why?  If we have a D converted to B, then it returns a Tiger, but a Tiger is an Animal, so we're OK.

This feature is called *return type covariance*, and it has been suggested for C# for, oh, some 15 years now, and has never been implemented.  It is not supported by the CLR, and it is not a high priority for the design team, and it creates new flavours of the Brittle Base Class Problem, and all these are such points against that it is unlikely to meet the bar any time soon.

C++ does support this feature, including on the CLR, so it is *possible* to do on the CLR.  You just end up having to generate a bunch of helper methods.

Of course we cannot have D.Frob return Animal.  It could return a Turtle, but B.Frob promises to only return Mammals.

What about the argument type?  It *could* be typesafe to have D.Frob take Shape.  Again, same reasoning: if we have a D converted to B then we will only get squares.  But it would not be safe to have D.Frob take a GreenSquare, because B.Frob promises to be able to take any square, not just green squares.

This feature is called *formal parameter type contravariance* and few languages implement it.

Now, you want return type covariance and formal parameter type *covariance*, which is neither supported *nor* typesafe. Interestingly enough, Eiffel supports this kind of covariance.

C# developers who want return type covariance usually end up doing something like:

```
class D : B {
  private Tiger FrobPrivate(Square s) { ... }
  public override Mammal Frob(Square s) 
  { 
    return this.FrobPrivate(s);
  }
  public new Tiger Frob(Square s)
  { 
    return this.FrobPrivate(s);
  }
}
```

Which is basically what the C# compiler would have to do on your behalf to implement the feature anyways.

Comment: Thanks for such a descriptive answer! This was a really interesting programming lesson. It seems that I'll need to rethink the whole idea again. The workaround with returning type covariance is interesting and I really appreciate that you gave that example. Maybe I would even be able to use it somehow in my code, however, I will try to find a way to actually avoid using this as I start to notice some mistakes in my way of thinking.